# Mixing audio android

Tags: java, android, api

I'm developing applications for Android. I need to have some kind of **audio mixing** effect.

How can I combine `2 or more audio tracks` into 1 `audio track`?

Or adding an audio track into a certain stream of an audio?

Can anyone give me samples where I can head start?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try [to port this code](http://code.google.com/p/mobikar/source/browse/mobiKAR/archive/tmp/src/MixingAudioInputStream.java?r=13) to Android?

> Mixing of multiple AudioInputStreams to one [AudioInputStream](http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Android/UnTagged/droid292/javax/sound/sampled/AudioInputStream.java.htm).
>           This class takes a collection of AudioInputStreams and mixes
>           them together. Being a subclass of AudioInputStream itself,
>           reading from instances of this class behaves as if the mixdown
>           result of the input streams is read

.